# Is there any difference between containers running with docker run or with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Having that question coming into my mind where I wanted to know how docker behaves in these different scenarios.

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  x:
    image: x
  y:
    image: y
```

**docker command**

```
docker run x
docker run y
```

Comment: no, compose is just a wrapper that lets you run the docker commands from a yaml file.

Comment: Docker compose sets up a default network among the containers, and also sets the container names to the service names. I'm not sure if that's all the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main different is you can't create resources (eg. network, volume) with `docker run`, you need to pre-create such resources before use (imperative). You can declare resources in the compose file and docker will create for you, including removal with `down` command. Compose works on group of services while the formal works on one at a time. Compose file can also used for `docker stack`, attributes not compatible with stack will be ignore automatically; where `docker run` has no support to Swarm mode.